# helm-org-rifle-directories: how to add many directories

Tags: org-mode

I read the instructions of this package ([helm-org-rifle](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-rifle)), but I couldn't manage how to select more than one directory interactively. Is this possible?

Comment: "... this package" - which package is that? Guessing from the title it could be `org-rifle` (which is unknown to me) or `helm-org-rifle` (which is also unknown to me). Instead of sending any potential answerers on possibly wild goose chases, why not provide a link to it/them?

Comment: helm-org-rifle is the name  ;) https://github.com/alphapapa/org-rifle